# I tried to make a driver to control the rotation speed of my object. When I try to animate it it seems to slow down. How do I fix the driver?

Tags: animation, rigging, drivers

[Blender file](https://easyupload.io/vftw2s)

Just a bunch of cubes and one single bone, with the custom property and the driver.

https://gfycat.com/coldablecowbird

So I've trying to work this a driver to control the rotation speed, to make the animation easier, and there seem to be an issue there: The model seems to exponentially speed up after the first keyframe, then slow down right before the second keyframe, and maintain constant speed. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the way I made the driver, although I'm not sure how to fix it.
Any ideas about what I can do?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong formula -> use this as formula, so you got constant speed.

It has nothing to do with interpolation.

[image]

You can change your custom property so that it allows higher values here: (your max value was 1, so that's why you couldn't make it quicker and i think that's why you tried to solve this with multiplying another value)

[image]

after you changed the maximum value of your speed, you can change the speed in the graph editor by selecting that point, then G and move your mouse up like this:

[image]

--- UPDATE:

to "automate" the rotation, delete the keyframes for speed and enter "#frame/10" into the speed value.

blend file to check out: [image]

Comment: I want the driver to automate the spinning. That's why I have the "var*time" expression. By removing the time factor, that means I need to manually spin the model, so the driver really doesn't do anything, right? I can just animate the both itself, without any limitation to the rotation. Am I getting right?

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more what your "end goal" is? What do you mean by "automate"? you mean it should rotate when the animation starts? just set "#frame/10" into your speed value. Then this would do it. of course first delete the keyframes in your speed value.

Comment: i updated my answer and added the blend file, so you can check it out

Comment: The end goal is to be able to control the rotation speed for easier animation. I want to have a gradual build up of the speed and then let the object rotate at the constant top speed. I have this aircraft the I try to rig. Is has a a minigun-like weapon. I want it to rotate gradually until it get to the top speed, stay there for a few second (while there is the shooting animation), and then slow down to a dead stop when the action is done.

Comment: There are also the propeller blades, that work in the same way. Instead of animating the propeller and the gun for the entire animation sequence, I thought it would be simpler to use driver for it. https://gfycat.com/shockingzanyindiancow

Comment: i think you cannot do this with drivers because to calculate a changing rotation speed it needs the "history" of the values of your speed. you cannot just multiply the angle with the frame, because this will always be a constant value, but if the speed changes the "angle" would jump and this would look really weird. So you need either a very intelligent python driver or animation nodes i think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134857/discussion-between-yogev-and-chris).